# The interface ColorSpace cannot define an initializer

Tags: java, android

```
public abstract interface Color
{


  public static final float[] xyz2sRGB;

  static
  {
    float[] arrayOfFloat = new float[9];
    arrayOfFloat[0] = 3.241F;
    arrayOfFloat[1] = -0.9692F;
    arrayOfFloat[2] = 0.0556F;
    arrayOfFloat[3] = -1.5374F;
    arrayOfFloat[4] = 1.876F;
    arrayOfFloat[5] = -0.204F;
    arrayOfFloat[6] = -0.4986F;
    arrayOfFloat[7] = 0.0416F;
    arrayOfFloat[8] = 1.057F;
    xyz2sRGB = arrayOfFloat;
  }
```

The compiler doesn't like the above code, returning the error:

```
The interface ColorSpace cannot define an initializer
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried removing the initializer? Apparently it’s not allowed in an `interface`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no initializer for interface. static or not. However, you can create an abstract class with static initializer. But remember that abstract class is not an interface, so you can only extend one such class.

```
public abstract class Color{
    public static final float[] xyz2sRGB;
      static
      {
        xyz2sRGB= new float[9];
        xyz2sRGB[0] = 3.241F;
        xyz2sRGB[1] = -0.9692F;
        xyz2sRGB[2] = 0.0556F;
        xyz2sRGB[3] = -1.5374F;
        xyz2sRGB[4] = 1.876F;
        xyz2sRGB[5] = -0.204F;
        xyz2sRGB[6] = -0.4986F;
        xyz2sRGB[7] = 0.0416F;
        xyz2sRGB[8] = 1.057F;
      } 
}
```

Comment: public abstract **class** Color

Comment: replace the `interface` with `class`.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract interface
```

sounds very wrong.

Either define an `abstract class` OR an `interface`. and interface won't support `static` initializers.

Simply replace the interface with class, in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply initialize the array with its declaration:

```
public interface Color {

    public static final float[] xyz2sRGB = {
        3.241F, -0.9692F, 0.0556F,
        -1.5374F, 1.876F, -0.204F,
        -0.4986F, 0.0416F, 1.057F
    };

}
```

Then you dont need your initializer and problem solved