# Eclipse not compiling generics

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, compiler-errors

I was trying to implement some test code from a class project provided by our professor, specifically generics, and upon the import and package placement all of the files that use generics report "Delete Token" Errors related to the  declaration. I have consulted with a few other students and theirs works. Mine seems to be the only one with these errors. I have updated my Java platform and I have attempted similar generic typing in blank projects only for it to give the same errors.

```
public interface maindisplay<T> {   //<-- Errors are on this line

}
```

The exact error messages are:

> Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
>   The interface maindisplay cannot define an initializer

Comment: The error seems to be somewhere else in your code, not in the code posted so far.

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling your project with J2SE 5.0 or higher?

Comment: You may have downloaded a new java, but did you set eclipse to use it properly?

Comment: I have verified that I am using 5.0 or higher. The code itself is giving compile errors. The First section of code I posted, the blank interface, will not compile due to the <E>, it seems eclipse is unable to utilize it. As for setting eclipse to use the new java I am unsure how to do it, may I ask how one may do that?

Comment: Open up Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE's. Add your J2SE there. Then in Preferences -> Java -> Compiler make sure the compiler compliance level is set to 1.5 or higher.

Comment: What is the exact error message? You can copy it easily from the "Problems View"

Comment: Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens maindisplay.java NodeListHW/src line 3

Comment: The interface maindisplay cannot define an initializer maindisplay.java NodeListHW/src line 3

Comment: Are you sure you use Java to compile this code? Sounds more like a Scala error message to me.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308723/the-interface-colorspace-cannot-define-an-initializer

Answer (score 0):

I checked and the code above compiles cleanly.

Either

- you omitted an important part of the code or
- you broke something in the project setup or
- you configured Java to throw an error for unused generic arguments (but the error message would be different)